# Replace Json value dynamically using Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

Currently, I am reading a Json String

```
{
type = animal,
configurationData = {
    type =  "herbivorous",
    address = "123, Windmill Road"
}
```

}

Now, I have to change the values after reading from some object. So, the updated value would be like

```
{
type = human,
configurationData = {
    type =  "vegeterian",
    address = "876, Borough Street"
}
```

}

and need to submit the updated String to remote service.  At present, I am doing like this.

1. Create the Java Object manually from input JSON String (using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
2. Populate the Java Object manually by calling setters.
3. Convert the updated Java Object to JSON and submit to remote service.

Here, I am seeing an unnecessary excercise of reading, populating and writing again before sending to remote service.

**Do we have any other to achieve this in better manner?** I was thinking to load the json template (using ObjectMapper) and just update the required keys in that Json Map and submit that Map to remove service.

Something like,

```
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + myJsonFile);
    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();

    JsonNode node  = mapper.readTree(inputStream);
    //Search Keys from Json and store in Map. use Map.replace(K,V) to replace value and submit that Map to remote.
```

But I am not getting the Search and store in Map operation correct. So any help on this would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your approach. I have tried it and worked for me. Does the code snippet below sound reasonable to you?

```
    @Test
    public void test_UpdateJsonString() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonStr = "{\"type\":\"animal\",\"configurationData\": {\"type\":\"herbivorous\",\"address\":\"123, Windmill Road\"}}";
        String targetJsonStr ="{\"type\":\"human\",\"configurationData\":{\"type\":\"vegeterian\",\"address\":\"876, Borough Street\"}}";
        Map<String, Object> mapJson = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr,new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
        Map<String, Object> mapTargetJson = objectMapper.readValue(targetJsonStr,new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});

        // either update all values or a particular property with mapJson.get(fieldName)
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> keyVal: mapTargetJson.entrySet()) {
            mapJson.replace(keyVal.getKey(),keyVal.getValue());
        }

        jsonStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mapJson);
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStr);
        String type = jsonNode.get("type").asText();
        assertEquals(type,"human");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom deserializer that does the job for you. You should register the custom reserializer in simple module and in turn rwgister the simple module to the object mapper. So, when the objectmapper does the deserialization, the data transformation is also taken care.

Now, you have the POJO with updated values. When you serialize this POJO to get a string, the default serializer will help you get what you expected.

This way, you dont deal with text manupulation but just resetting the property values in POJO during deserialization.

[Sample for custom deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this example would require a Model class to be created. But in my case, I am having 70+ different payloads against which I would have to create 70+ different models. Isn't it?

Comment: What does your requirement have to do with jackson? You are not manipulating the properties but the values. You could transform the values post de-serialization of the json into POJO. Use appropriate setters.